# ¿Cómo crear un textbox a partir de un bucle for?

Tags: java, bucle-for, java-swing

Tengo dos formularios, en uno coloco el número de ecuaciones y el otro debería construir tantos jtextbox como el número que coloque en el otro jframe 'public':

```
void Mostrar(){
        for (int i = 0; i < NumeroDeEcuaciones; i++) {
            JTextField input = new JTextField("texto por defecto",20); 
            this.add(input);
       } 
    }
```

Pero no me crea los textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que te sirva

```
 JTextField [] campos = new JTextField[numeroDeCampos];
 columna=20;
 fila=10;
 for(int i=0;i<numeroDeCampos;i++)
 {
   campos[i]= new JTextField();
   campos[i].bounds(columna,fila,80,20);
   this.add(campos[i]);
   fila+=30
}
```

se van agregando parcialmente *30px* hacia abajo.